# Pass table as argument to postgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, function, arguments, bulkinsert

is it possible to pass table/list/json as argument to postgreSQL function from .net core API? The requirement is like for an invoice, there are multiple line items. so we want to save invoice first and then it's respective multiple line items. for line items, we have to either call postgreSQL function one by one and insert line item to DB. so just checking if SQL bulk inset like functionality is available in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(table sometable) 
RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, vendor_id bigint) 
BEGIN
 -- bulk or single insert multiple records from argument table into postgreSQL table
END;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Passing json as argument to a postgres is very easy, much more than a table or a list. Then you can break down the json inside the postgres function in order to insert the invoice first and then the list of invoice items.

Comment: Thanks @Edouard, I have searched and now I am passing json to postgresql function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came to know that json can be passed to postgresql function and there are plenty of functionality is available to extract value from json in postgresql function makes life easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).